# construct topology on $[0,1)$ so that it becomes homeomorphic to $ S^1$

Tags: general-topology

construct topology on $[0,1)$ so that it becomes homeomorphic to $ S^1$. what is the homeomorphism map $f: [0,1) --> S^1$

this question is from my past exam, but still I cannot solve. Any idea is appreciated

Comment: Try $f(x)=\langle \cos 2\pi x,\sin 2\pi x\rangle$: you’re just wrapping the interval around the circle.

Comment: Hint: It might be easier to state the map first and let it induce the topology such that it becomes a homeomorphism.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In terms of the topology though, do you just assign open sets based on $f^{-1}(U)$, $U$ open in $S^1$?

Comment: @snulty: Yes, that’s exactly what’s needed.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott normally they are not homeomorphic, you can read Gyu Eun Lee (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/52450/gyu-eun-lee), $[0, 1)$ and $S^1$ not homeomorphic?, URL (version: 2014-07-08): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/860300

Comment: @user365: Of course they’re not homeomorphic with their usual topologies: $S^1$ is compact, and $[0,1)$ isn’t. (Alternatively, $[0,1)$ has cutpoints, and $S^1$ doesn’t.) That’s beside the point. The point is that if you have any bijection $f:[0,1)\to S^1$, the family of sets $f^{-1}[U]$ such that $U$ is open in $S^1$ is automatically a topology on $[0,1)$ making it homeomorphic to $S^1$ (where $S^1$ has its usual topology). I just suggested what is probably the simplest bijection, but any would do equally well.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry,  I misunderstood you, thanks a lot.

Comment: @user365: No problem.

Answer (score 7):

Given any bijection $f:X\to Y$ between two sets and a topology $T$ on $Y$, there is a unique topology $T'$ on $X$ for which $f$ is a homeomorphism, namely $T'=\{f^{-1}(U):U\in T\}$.  So just pick any bijection $f:[0,1)\to S^1$ and take the topology $T'$ on $[0,1)$ constructed in this way from the standard topology $T$ on $S^1$.

Answer (score 3):

Neighborhoods of $0$: $[0,\delta_1)\cup(1-\delta_2,1)$