# Proof that a function is not a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

To show that a mapping $$\phi:[0,1)\to S^1 $$ is not a homeomorphism.

The conditions for being a homeomorphism are firstly the mapping should be bijective and second the maps $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ should be continuous.

The first condition of bijectivity is of one to one and onto.
The circle could be thought of $$\phi(t)=(\cos2\pi t,\sin2\pi t)$$
How to show that $\phi ^{-1}$ 
$$\phi^{-1}(u,v)=\bigg(\frac{\cos^{-1} u}{2\pi},\frac{\sin^{-1} v}{2\pi}\bigg)$$
is not continuous?

Comment: Do you have a specific function $\phi$, and you want to show it is not a homeomorphism?  Or do you want to show there is *no* homeomorphism from $[0,1)$ to $S^1$?

Comment: this is quite relevant (I am not sure whether duplicate applies because the questions are not identical) to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562048/how-do-i-show-that-f-0-1-to-s1-ft-cos2-pi-t-sin2-pi-t-is and to: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860229/0-1-and-s1-not-homeomorphic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a function $\phi:X\to Y$, between two topological spaces is a  homeomorphism if it is bijective, continuous, with continuous inverse $\phi^{-1}:Y\to X$. Recall also, that for any bijective function we have:
$$
\phi:\textrm{continuous } \Leftrightarrow \phi^{-1}:\textrm{open}, \ \ \textrm{ and } \ \ \phi:\textrm{open } \Leftrightarrow \phi^{-1}:\textrm{continuous}
$$
so we can equivalently state that: a function $\phi:X\to Y$, between two topological spaces is a homeomorphism if it is bijective, continuous and open.

**The function $\phi: [0,1) \rightarrow \mathcal{S}^{1}$, given by $\phi(t) = (\cos2 \pi t, \sin2 \pi t)$ is continuous and bijective but it is not open (equivalently: its inverse function $\phi^{-1}: \mathcal{S}^{1} \rightarrow [0,1)$ is not continuous):**

**Proof:**
To see that, let us recall that here, the space $Y=\mathcal{S}^{1}$ is equipped with its relative topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the space $X=[0,1)$  is equipped with its relative topology as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Notice that in this relative topology, $[0,t)$ for $0<t<1$, is an open subset of $[0,1)$. Now, it is easy to see that the image $\phi\big([0,t)\big)\subseteq\mathcal{S}^1$ is not an open subset of $\mathcal{S}^1$ (in its relative topology). Therefore, $\phi$ is not open or equivalently $\phi^{-1}$ is not continuous.

So, $\phi$ is not a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The space $S^1$ is compact but $[0,1)$ is not compact, hence these spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Hence, this also implies not only that OP's $\phi$ is not an homeomorphism, but also that no such an homeomorphism exists.